# Google Cloud platform - vertex AI unable to get a100 GPU instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bioinformatics, google-cloud-vertex-ai

So I've been getting this error constantly.

`The zone 'projects/xxxxx/zones/Asia-northeast3-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.`

Now based on my previous research, this shows unavailability in the zone, and I've been trying all different zones since Saturday to no avail. I am looking to requisition the A100 GPU with the a2-highgpu-1g machine on the VERTEX AI.

I am trying to deploy an alphafold notebook for this particular case along with a predefined docker custom environment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/running-alphafold-on-vertexai

Docker link: us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/cloud-devrel-public-resources/alphafold/alphafold-on-gcp:latest

Now even though I am running a trial account, I have put in the card details and have upgraded to a full account. I also believe I've set the quotas.

Has anyone else faced this issue or am I doing anything wrong?

Any advice would honestly be appreciated

Comment: That seems to be a regular stockout. You should try Reservation or probably want to talk with support team or your Account team to look into this.

Comment: I see. This has been a royal pain. Hopefully GCP has the H100 GPUs soon and people shift to that.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked up your error message and it pointed me to zone-related limitations but based on our published documents, the zone ***[Asia-northeast3-a](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#:%7E:text=asia%2Dnortheast3%2Da,GPUs)*** that you have used should be able to manage an ***[a2-highgpu-1g](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/accelerator-optimized-machines#a2-standard-vms:%7E:text=bandwidth%20(Gbps)%E2%80%A1-,a2%2Dhighgpu%2D1g,-1)*** machine type that is capable to run a ***[NVIDIA A100 40GB](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#a100-40gb:%7E:text=A100%2080GB-,GPU%20model,Yes,-a2%2Dhighgpu%2D2g)*** GPU model.

Kindly review this [A2 standard limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/accelerator-optimized-machines#a2_standard_limitations) and [Machine family and series recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-resource#:%7E:text=M3%2C%20M2%2C%20M1-,A2%2C%20G2,-Day%2Dto%2Dday) documents as it can provide you with insights for [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/troubleshooting#insufficient_resources_in_a_region).

You can submit this to our [Issue tracking system and product feature requests](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) as it might be related to a [Service Health incident](https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/34NK3hoNFQhCenBdxHqk) reported Sep. 25, 2023.  Getting a [Vertex AI support](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/support/getting-support) is also an option  that you can explore for better assistance.